# Solve $\log_{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}(x^2+2x-2)=\log_{{2+\sqrt{3}}}(x^2+2x-3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I solve this equation?
$$\log_{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}(x^2+2x-2)=\log_{{2+\sqrt{3}}}(x^2+2x-3)$$

---

$$\frac{\log _{2+\sqrt{3}}\left(x^2+2x-2\right)}{\log _{2+\sqrt{3}}\left(2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)}=\log _{2+\sqrt{3}}\left(x^2+2x-3\right)$$

$$\frac{\log _{2+\sqrt{3}}\left(x^2+2x-2\right)}{\log _{2+\sqrt{3}}2+0,5}=\log _{2+\sqrt{3}}\left(x^2+2x-3\right)$$

Let $t=x^2+2x-2$, so
$$\frac{\log _{2+\sqrt{3}}t}{\log _{2+\sqrt{3}}2+0,5}=\log _{2+\sqrt{3}}\left(t-1\right)$$
...

Comment: what kind of base has the left logarithm?

Comment: $2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$ or $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$?

Comment: Considering logarithms to such bases is **sick**. There are enough real problems involving logs to various bases at stake.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I disagree.  This exercise exists solely to test ones thorough understanding of log as abstraction.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $\log_{2+\sqrt{3}}(x^2+2x-3) = \log_{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}$

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the logarithm base so that each side of the equation has a logarithm of the same base.

You can change logarithms using this property:

$$ log_{a}{x}= \frac{log_{b}x}{log_{b}a}   $$

Comment: Hm, that's an idea.